# На чем в UI отобразить данные типа: Название - значение

Tags: java, android, android-ui

Есть Активити и на нем по середине (занимает большую часть активити) свободное пространство куда могу вложить, что нибудь для отображения моих данных. Фрагмент ставить не хочу. Что есть из готовых и простых решений, чтобы отобразить список данных. Если я хочу использовать ListView, мне придется делать это во фрагменте?

Логика такая: Открывается активити, сразу по уставленным дефолтным значениям подгружаются данные из сети в AsyncTask и окончанию загрузки должны отобразиться. Если использую фрагмент, не возникнет такой проблемы: данные подгрузились, а из AsyncTask не смогу обновить фрагмент.

Comment: Правильно ли будет использовать инферфейс с обратным вызовом из AsyncTask в фрагмент, чтобы тот обновился по окончанию работы 
 в AsyncTask .?

Comment: Что Вас побудило в данной ситуации использовать фрагмент? Какая в нем необходимость?

Comment: Как я понял никакой. Я думал нельзя будет использовать ListView, но оказывается с ним нет никаких проблем. Единственное я хотел бы видеть не список в один столбец, а несколько столбцов. Как я понимаю GridView подойдет, верно? А если я хочу над списком кнопки для сортировки, вроде хорошо подходит TabHost, только вот не знаю можно ли будет в нем разбить по столбцам как в GridView?